# How to solve Java Database Connectivity Problem In JDK 17. How to solve xception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver

Tags: java, database

```
public class DEMO {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

I got this error message when I try to run Above Code

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver

Comment: by making sure all the classes you are trying to use are actually on your classpath.

Comment: Java classes should not be all uppercased. In this case, following standard Java class naming conventions, the class should be named "Demo."

Comment: That error shouldn’t be possible unless you have a module-info.java in your project.  If you do, please edit your question and show us the contents of that file.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for dependency management? I'm using Maven, and the above "works" for me when I define the (most-recent) MySQL Connector/J driver as a dependency.

From my `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <version>8.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```